# Maps with multiple types of values in java

Tags: java, types, dictionary, key

I have to accomplish a strange peculiar scenario. Its described as follows:

I have to design a Map where the '**Keys**' are always of **String** type. However, the '**Value**' for one of the key may be a **String or a List**(depends on the number of values a particular key can have. 'Value' will be a String if that particular key has only one value and it has to be a List if the key contains many values). How to accomplish this scenario?

For Example: there are 2 keys in a map namely "Name" and "Phone Nos". A person can have only one name and multiple phone numbers. So here the first key i.e. "Name" should have 'String' type for Value, whereas for the second key i.e. "Phone Nos" should have 'List' type for Value. How to declare such a Map. Is it possible?

Comment: Same homework assignment as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259997/in-java-how-can-i-work-with-objects-which-can-be-either-string-or-liststring ???

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is possible to do something like `Map<String, Object>`.

**But**: I would strongly suggest to think your design over. You should use a class for your persons instead. That way you could do: `Map<String, Person>` with `Person` having getters and setters for names, phone numbers and other information.

Example `Person` class:

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private List<String> phoneNumbers = Collections.emptyList();

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumbers(List<String> phoneNumbers) {
        this.phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers;
    }

    public void addPhoneNumber(String number) {
        phoneNumbers.add(number);
    }

    public List<String> getPhoneNumbers() {
        return phoneNumbers;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Of course there is. Pick your poison:

```
Map<String, Object> mixed = new HashMap<String, Object>();

Map<String, Serializable> mixed = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
Map mixed = new HashMap();
```

Comment: Could you explain what is happening there?

Answer (score 3):

Well, why not make a `Map<String, List<String>>`? you could always just add one element to your list if there is just one value or use a common supertype of String and List, thus you would get

```
Map<String, Object>
```

Comment: The users asks for a way to use this structure:
`"Name" -> "Sam Something", "Phone Nos" -> "1234", "5678"` which still wont work with your example.

Comment: Guava's `ListMultimap` is a better collection to use rather than `Map<X, List<Y>>`

Comment: @nfechner: why wouldn't it work? object can be anything what can be represented in java, or am i missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

I would do one of the following:

1. Use a `Multimap<String, String>`. The [Multimap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html) would contain one or more values associated with each key.
2. Use a `Map<String, Either<String, List<String>>>`. Use a [Either](https://docs.atlassian.com/fugue/1.2.0/apidocs/com/atlassian/fugue/Either.html) to distinguish between a single or multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make a PhoneNumber wrapper class that exposes an API for soring either one or multipel phone numbers and then can retrieve either one or all (multiple) phone numbers and then make a map of String and PhoneNumber? Something like:

```
class PhoneNumber {


  private String[] phoneNumbers;


  public void storePhoneNumber(String... phoneNumbers) {
     this.phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers;
  }

  public String getPhoneNumber() {
    if(phoneNumbers.length>=1) {
      return phoneNumbers[0];
    } else {
      return null;
    }

  }

  public List<String> getPhoneNumbers() {
    if(phoneNumbers!=null) {
      return Arrays.asList(phoneNumbers);
    } else {
      return null;
    }

  }
```

}