# In java, how can I work with objects which can be either String or List<String>?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Maps with multiple types of values in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259906/maps-with-multiple-types-of-values-in-java)

I have an odd question. Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way, but let's see where this question goes :)

I would like a Map container that contains either Strings or lists of Strings. I want to enforce this rule during construction of this object so that you can't create a map with values that aren't either of those.

e.g.

```
class Record {
  public Record(String key, Map<String,Object> attrs) {
    // check that attrs only contains Objects which are Strings or List<Strings>
  }
}
```

Other ways I have thought of to solve the problem might be...

1)

```
class Record {
  public Record(String key, Map<String,String> attrs, Map<String,List<String>> multiAttrs) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

2)

```
class Record {
  public Record(String key, Map<String,Value> attrs) {
    // ...
  }
}

class Value {
  // Create some funky class that encapsulates lists.
  // Perhaps returning the only element in the list if the size is 1,
  // but returning the list otherwise
}
```

I am not immediately excited at the alternatives, but I'm just putting it there as stuff I've already considered. Really I want the distinction between Strings and List to be transparent to the user of the class.

Comment: The third idea is the best I can think of. I would also look at multimaps from Guava libraries as epoch proposed.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered [ListMultimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html)? For the single value case the list would only have one element. `Multimap` allows multiple elements (values) to be mapped to each key. So your method would be:

```
public Record(String key, ListMultimap<String, String> attrs)...
```

Also, since your `Record` seems to be another mapping, consider using [Table](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html) which allows for two-key mapping.

Comment: +1 for also thinking about guava!

Answer (score 2):

Check out [ArrayListMultimap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html) from Google which will help with this need

You can continue calling put on this map, if you need to get the map in its simplified form you can use this method, or modify it :)

```
public static Map<Field, String> toSingularMap(ArrayListMultimap<Field, String> map) {
    Map<Field, String> singular_map = new HashMap<Field, String>();
    if (map != null && !map.isEmpty()) {
        Map<Field, Collection<String>> real_map = map.asMap();
        for (Iterator<Entry<Field, Collection<String>>> it = real_map
                .entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            Entry<Field, Collection<String>> entry = it.next();
            Field field = entry.getKey();
            Collection<String> values = entry.getValue();

            String value = null;
            if (values != null && !values.isEmpty()) {
                ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(values);
                value = list.get(0);
            }

            singular_map.put(field, value);
        }
    }

    return singular_map;
}
```

Or if you do not want to use an extra library, you can create a simple Wrapper class

```
class Wrap {
    String value;
    String[] values
}
```

and have your map use `Map<String, Wrap> map`, when looping you can then determine either through use of your class methods or just testing, which one of the Wrapper variables are populated

Comment: I don't get this method. `Multimap` is designed to allow for multiple values for each key. This method only extracts the first value for each key. If that was the case, why not use a `Map`?

Comment: I know, I use this method for older parts of my system where multimaps were not yet introduced, and the API expects a normal `Map<String, String>();` I only put it here to demonstrate the OP can do the same (use a single map or the multimap), or not :). it just shows the basics of the Multimap :)

Answer (score 2):

I would use only `List<String>`. You could maybe add some methods to allow adding a single String and wrap the passed argument using `Arrays.asList(...)`. Using only a single type of objects will reduce the quantity of code to write and avoid many `if/else`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a class

```
class MyFunkyValue{

private String onlyOneString;
private List<String> stringValues;

public MyFunkyValue(String s){
...
}

public MyFunkyValue(List<String>ls){
...
}
}
```

and use it like this:

```
Map<KeyClass,MyFunkyValue> m;
```

Comment: This in combination with `Optional` or `Either` might work nicely.